# Compute the definite integral $\int_{-1}^12\sqrt{4x^2+9x^4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm attempting to evaluate the following definite integral

$$\int_{-1}^2 \sqrt{4x^2+9x^4}dx$$

First, we re-write it as (perhaps this is where the error occurs as I do not include the absolute value):

$$\int_{-1}^2 x\sqrt{4+9x^2}dx$$

Then, we easily find the anti-derivative by substituting $u=4+9x^2$, which gives us:
$$\frac{1}{27}\left[(9x^2+4)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{-1}^2=\frac{1}{27}(40^{\frac{3}{2}}-13^{\frac{3}{2}}).$$
However, the answer ought to be:
$$\frac{1}{27}(40^{\frac{3}{2}}+13^{\frac{3}{2}}-16).$$

Where did I go wrong? Thank you for your input

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} \ne x$ so your first rewrite is indeed wrong, as you suspected.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ makes the integrand odd, so the integrals over $[0,1]$ and $[-1,0]$ cancel out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that as you mentioned, $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| \ne x$, but there is an easy remedy: you can split the integral domain to 2 integrals over $(-1,0)$ and $(0,2)$, and then your technique will work for the second one straight up, and for the first one you will need to take out $-x$ instead.

In other words,
$$
\int_{-1}^2 \sqrt{4x^2+9x^4}dx
 = \int_{-1}^0 (-x) \sqrt{4+9x^2} dx
 + \int_0^2 x \sqrt{4+9x^2} dx
$$